# Getting a list of tabe contents based on column value of different table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have couple of tables.

Table A:

| PName | PComment | isTierI | isTierII | isTierIII | lastValueUsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOX | row | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| FREEZER | row | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| BOTTLE | row | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| BUILDING | row | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Another table that I have is as follows:

Table B:

| Name | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| BOX#1 | row |
| BOX#2 | row |
| BOTTLE#1 | row |
| BOTTLE#2 | row |
| BOTTLE#3 | row |
| BUILDING#1 | row |
| FREEZER#1 | row |

I have categorized the three types of PName column using tier columns. For example, BOX can go inside FREEZER so BOX is in tier III and FREEZER is in Tier II and since Freezer can go inside a building, building is tierI. The last value used column shows how many box, freezer, bottle or building are in table B.

In Table B - it's pretty cear I think that since last Value used column value of BOX is 2, we have two boxes, like BOX#1 and BOX#2. Similarly for BOTTLE, FREEZER and BUILDING

Both tabes have id column as well which is primary key and I haven't shown it above just to keep it concise. Both tables are not linked to each other.

If I want to get only the list of BOTTLE ( like BOTTLE#1, BOTTLE#2 and BOTTLE#3) from Table B based on the lastValueUsed column vaue of `3` from Table A, is it possibe to do it via a SQL?

Comment: Are there any other columns that relate the two tables together? If not, is the naming convention for `Table2.Name` always `Name#Number`?

Comment: There aren't any other columns that create the two tables together.  Yes, the naming convention for `Table2.Name` always `Name#Number`